# Tell "ls -laR /": do not recurse into other filesystems

Tags: ls

I occasionally do "ls -laR /" on my system and offsite backup the
results. If disaster strikes, I'll at least know which files I've lost.

I recently started sshfs mounting remote systems, yielding two problems:

- "ls -laR" on sshfs mounted systems is painfully slow
- I don't need the "ls -laR" results of remote filesystems, at least
  not locally.

What's the ls equivalent of find's "-xdev" option or du's "-x" option?

In case there's a better way to do it, my goal is to efficiently get a
list of all files on my hard drive with size, owner, mod time, etc. In
other words, all the info "ls -l" would normally provide.

I've considered: "find / -xdev | xargs ls -la", but I sense that would
be less efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such option for `ls` itself, but you can do

```
find / -xdev -ls
```

or if that is not sufficiently detailed, look into the possibilities offered by the `-printf` option.

Comment: Thank you, fantastic! You've literally answered the question faster than I can approve it.... but I will in 4m.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-ls` action with `find(1)`, which prints out the file stats like `ls -dils` would:

```
find / -xdev -ls
```

If the `ls -dils` format isn't your thing, you can also use the `-exec ... +` action, which works similarly to `xargs(1)` but is more efficient:

```
find / -xdev -exec ls -l '{}' +
```

The `+` instructs `find` to pass as many filenames as it can into the subprocess, so it only spawns as few subprocesses as necessary (which is determined by the maximum size of command line arguments on your OS).  If you use a `;` instead of `+`, then `find` creates one process per file, which is very slow when you have a lot of files, so that's not recommended.